# ASM. Clone JumpInsnNode correctly

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

Do you know the way how to clone JumpInsnNode correctly?

I tried several things:

```
1. endList.add(insn.clone(labelNodes));
```

insn is JumpInsnNode here;
labelNodes - all labelNodes in the method.
This code throws NullPointerException because of implementation of clone method that calls clone method from AbsractInsnNode class:

```
static LabelNode clone(final LabelNode label, final Map<LabelNode, LabelNode> map) {
        return map.get(label);
    }
```

This method returns null.

2. `endList.add(new JumpInsnNode(insn.getOpcode(), new LabelNode(insn.label.getLabel())));`

It throws an exception:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at org.objectweb.asm.Frame.a(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.Frame.a(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.MethodWriter.visitMaxs(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodNode.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodNode.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.ClassNode.accept(Unknown Source)
    at com.smartbear.real.agent.Agent.transform(Agent.java:221)
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:424)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.redefineClasses0(Native Method)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.redefineClasses(InstrumentationImpl.java:170)
    at com.smartbear.real.agent.Agent.agentmain(Agent.java:118)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:382)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallAgentmain(InstrumentationImpl.java:407)
```

The reasoning: I need to have ability to load method return values once again. I was able to do this with other types of instruction. However this type of instruction: `return (test != null);` doesn't work for me now. Byte code for this:

```
  LINENUMBER 112 L2
    ALOAD 3: tr
    IFNULL L3
    ICONST_1
    IRETURN
   L3
   FRAME APPEND [Boolean]
    ICONST_0
    IRETURN
```

Comment: What do you mean with “to load method return values once again” and why do you want to do that?

Comment: I'm instrumenting a code. My goal is to get return values for all methods and to pass that values to some helper function. So under "to load method return values once again" I mean: 1. to call helper function with actual input param - return value of methods in client's code once client's code was run and method was called; 2. to allow client's code running with instrumenting like without instrumenting (instrumenting here is an analog of some logging system).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are using the wrong approach. You shouldn’t clone arbitrary instructions to replicate the return values, not only does this become unnecessarily complex, it might also replicate side-effects thus create unintended behavior different than without Instrumentation.

Replicating the value, a method is about to return, is much simpler. Right before one of the `…RETURN` instructions is executed, there must be the actual return value on the operand stack. So all you have to do, is to insert an appropriate `DUP` instruction (either `DUP` or `DUP2`) before the `…RETURN` instruction to duplicate the value. Then you can insert your logging code consuming that duplicated value.

E.g. you may change occurrences of `IRETURN` to:

```
DUP
INVOKESTATIC java/lang/Integer valueOf (I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
INVOKESTATIC MyLogger logReturnValue (Ljava/lang/Object;)V
IRETURN // the original return instruction
```

or `DRETURN` to:

```
DUP2
INVOKESTATIC java/lang/Double valueOf (D)Ljava/lang/Double;
INVOKESTATIC MyLogger logReturnValue (Ljava/lang/Object;)V
DRETURN // the original return instruction
```

or `ARETURN` to:

```
DUP
INVOKESTATIC MyLogger logReturnValue (Ljava/lang/Object;)V
ARETURN // the original return instruction
```

etc.

Comment: It makes sense. Thanks a lot! I will try your approach.